# VBscript to confirm list of files exist and have been modified same day

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to create a script that will scan a directory for a list of specific file names and will then check whether or not the DateLastModified is newer than prior day.

If any of the files do not exist or do exist but are not 'fresh' then I would like a summary window to pop up at the end listing the file names that did not meet the criteria.

As an example we can say the path is C:\Testing\
and the Files I want to scan for are File1.txt, File2.txt and File3.txt
**Note:** Although these files all have the same extension I do not want to scan for them that way. I want to specifically identify the files in my script since there are other txt files located in the directory.

**Update:**Here is what I was able to create as far as handling one file at a time. Any help you can offer will be greatly appreciated.

```
Option Explicit

Dim FSO
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim InputFile1
InputFile1 = ("C:\Testing\File1.txt")

Dim InputFile2
InputFile2 = ("C:\Testing\File2.txt")

Dim InputFile3
InputFile3 = ("C:\Testing\File3.txt")

Dim CurrentDate, OldDate

'* Default Date format is MM/DD/YYYY
CurrentDate = Date()
OldDate = Date() - 1

WScript.Echo ("The Current Date on the system is set to " & CurrentDate) & VbCrLf & ("Checking if the file is newer than " & OldDate)

If FSO.FileExists(InputFile1) Then
        If CDATE (FSO.GetFile(InputFile1).DateLastModified) > OldDate Then
        WScript.Echo ("All good!")
    Else
        WScript.Echo ("File is not current.")
    End If

Else
    WScript.Echo ("File does not exist.")
    Wscript.Quit
    End If
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, what have you tried ?

Comment: Hello Uri! I don't currently have anything because I don't know where to begin handling multiple files and essentially 3 checks (1. does the file exist? 2. what is the DateLastModified? 3. Is the file fresh?) Also, I'm not sure how to report the results once the script is finished rather than after each time it checks a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And if you like to add a Logfile of course try like this :

```
Option Explicit
Dim Ws,FSO,files,file,oldDate,LogFile
Set Ws = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
files = Array("C:\Testing\File1.txt", "C:\Testing\File2.txt", "C:\Testing\File3.txt")
oldDate = Date() - 1
WScript.Echo "Checking if any files are older than " & OldDate
LogFile = Left(Wscript.ScriptFullName, InstrRev(Wscript.ScriptFullName, ".")) & "log"
if fso.FileExists(LogFile) Then 
    fso.DeleteFile LogFile
end If

For Each file In files
    If FSO.FileExists(file) Then
        If FSO.GetFile(file).DateLastModified < oldDate Then
            WScript.Echo "Not current: " & DblQuote(file)
            WriteLog "Not current: " & DblQuote(file),LogFile
        End If
    Else
        WScript.Echo "Not found:   " & DblQuote(file)
        WriteLog "Not found:   " & DblQuote(file),LogFile
    End If
Next
if fso.FileExists(LogFile) Then 
    Ws.Run DblQuote(LogFile)
end If
'**********************************************************
Sub WriteLog(strText,LogFile)
    Dim fs,ts 
    Const ForAppending = 8
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fs.OpenTextFile(LogFile,ForAppending,True)
    ts.WriteLine strText
    ts.Close
End Sub
'***********************************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'***********************************************************
```

**EDIT : 26/04/2015** ==> Here is how to set a RootFolder into a variable

```
Option Explicit
Dim Ws,FSO,files,file,oldDate,LogFile,RootFolder
Set Ws = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
RootFolder = "c:\Testing"
Set RootFolder = fso.GetFolder(RootFolder)
oldDate = Date() - 1
WScript.Echo "Checking if any files are older than " & OldDate
LogFile = Left(Wscript.ScriptFullName, InstrRev(Wscript.ScriptFullName, ".")) & "log"
if fso.FileExists(LogFile) Then 
    fso.DeleteFile LogFile
end If

For Each file In RootFolder.files
    If FSO.FileExists(file) Then
        If FSO.GetFile(file).DateLastModified < oldDate Then
            WScript.Echo "Not current: " & DblQuote(file)
            WriteLog "Not current: " & DblQuote(file),LogFile
        End If
    Else
        WScript.Echo "Not found:   " & DblQuote(file)
        WriteLog "Not found:   " & DblQuote(file),LogFile
    End If
Next
if fso.FileExists(LogFile) Then 
    Ws.Run DblQuote(LogFile)
end If
'**********************************************************
Sub WriteLog(strText,LogFile)
    Dim fs,ts 
    Const ForAppending = 8
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fs.OpenTextFile(LogFile,ForAppending,True)
    ts.WriteLine strText
    ts.Close
End Sub
'***********************************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'***********************************************************
```

Comment: There's no need to use `Call` to call a sub. Just call it like you call `WScript.Echo`.

Comment: Ok, in this case i must omit the parenthesis  ;)

Comment: That's correct. So in all you get to write 6 characters less for the same effect. ;)

Comment: @Tomalak ==> To please you I edited my post and I followed your advice
Thank you ;)

Comment: Don't do it to please me, do it if you think it makes sense.

Comment: Hackoo, Thank you for your help. Overall I wanted to write the results of each file to a log that I could review once the script has completed. This is very helpful and I have learned a lot from your code. Thanks again!

Comment: One more question, how can I set the Directory path in a variable so that in my array I don't have to list out the full path of each file?

Answer (score 1):

You could use an array and a loop.

```
Option Explicit
Dim FSO
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim files, file, oldDate
files = Array("C:\Testing\File1.txt", "C:\Testing\File2.txt", "C:\Testing\File3.txt")
oldDate = Date() - 1

WScript.Echo "Checking if any files are older than " & OldDate

For Each file In files
    If FSO.FileExists(file) Then
        If FSO.GetFile(file).DateLastModified < oldDate Then
            WScript.Echo "Not current: " & file
        End If
    Else
        WScript.Echo "Not found:   " & file
    End If
Next
```

General tip: If you find yourself creating variables with a trailing counter (`file1`, `file2`, ...) then it's very probably that you *actually* want an array.

Comment: @Hackoo Thanks a lot for spotting my copy/past mistakes. Feeling a bit bad now. :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Tomalak! I was looking into Array's but I couldn't figure out how to Loop through the files. After reviewing your code it makes sense to me now, thanks again!